# Find the real eigen value of the following matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the given matrix, only one eigen value is real. What is that eigen value ?

\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  5&  4&  3& 2\\ 
 2&  1&  5&  4& 3\\ 
 3&  2&  1&  5& 4\\ 
 4&  3&  2&  1& 5\\ 
 5&  4&  3&  2& 1
\end{bmatrix}

---

Is there any small approach ?

Comment: @Moo, it just completely amazes me how some people can just pull up some obscure result like that so quickly.

Comment: Observe that the totals of the rows/columns are all equal. Act then by the matrix at the vector $x=(1,1,1,1,1)^T.$ You'll see that $Ax=15x,$ and so 15 is a real eigenvalue.